# Обновление gradle до версии 3.2.2

Tags: gradle

Установил Андроид студию 2020.3.1 патч 3. Пытаюсь преобразовать .apk в .aab. Нажимаю **Build - Generate Signed Bundle / APK...**, а там, соответственно, Android App Bundle. При нажатии "Далее", появляется предупреждение:

[image: Выдает такое предупреждение при попытке конвертации в .aab]

Я уже перечитал кучу форумов по обновлению Gradle, но нигде не встречается именно то, что у меня. Ибо в настройках Андроид студии для gradle нет такого количества возможных настроек. В директории самого проекта также нет Gradle Scripts, чтобы там изменить используемую версию gradle. Что я делаю не так!?

Изначально apk был создан в Unity.

Comment: Внизу экрана, где служебные поля, должно быть что-то типа update. Там нужно нажать кнопку run

Comment: Пока ничего подобного найти не могу

Comment: Если нажать выделенный синим текст, всплывает окно со следующими строками: 

Building Android App Bundles requires you to update to the latest version of the Android Gradle Plugin. Learn More  
App bundles allow you to support multiple device configurations from a single build artifact. App stores that support the bundle format use it to build and sign your APKs for you, and serve those APKs to users as needed.

Там можно нажать Update. Но, при нажатии окно закрывается, а внизу появляется надпись: No occurrences found

Comment: Попробуй просто выставить нужную версию в gradle файле, может, потянет автоматически.

Comment: Беда в том, что я даже этот файл найти не могу. Нашел некоторое решение - когда билдишь в Unity .aab файл, можно добавить созданный до этого ключ. Очень непонятная система, если честно...

Comment: Какой файл? Gradle? Чего его искать, он в структуре проекта явно показан